# How to paid gas charges from another account when transfer bep20 token using web3?

Tags: token, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js, bep20

```
let contract= new web3.eth.Contract(BUSD_TOKEN_ABI, BUSD_TOKEN_ADDRESS)
await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, transFerValue).send({from: defaultAddress})
```

I can send easily bep20 token by using above code from one address to another and its work fine, but in this case I need to pay the gas fee from defaultAddress. But I want to pay the gas fee from another account. Is there any way to pay the gas fee from another account when transfer the bep20 token using web3?
I searched a lot but not found any proper answer. If anyone know the answer please response with proper guideline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

I'm assuming your goal is to not pay any fees by the token owner, so the `approve()` function is out of question as well. If that's not the case, the token owner can invoke the `approve()` function (paying gas fees for it; allowing a specified spender to spend their tokens), and then the spender can invoke the `transferFrom()` specifying from which address (the owner who approved them to spend the tokens) they want to transfer the tokens.

There are some token contracts that allow metatransfers by accepting a message signed by the token owner to a custom function that is invoked by the transaction sender - effectively transferring tokens from the owner and all fees paid by the tx sender. But that requires a custom implementation that the BUSD contract (as well as most token contracts) doesn't implement.